# Motherboard doesn't POST with pci network card plugged in, but both motherboard and network card work fine if network card is hot-plugged

Tags: drivers, bios, motherboard, pci-express, pci

I recently got my hands on some old computer parts. An Asrock H61m-DPS motherboard, an intel i3-2120, and a D-link DGE-530T rev-B2 PCI gigabit ethernet card.

After I finished building this PC, I noticed something odd. If the network card is plugged in, the computer doesn't start at all. like nothing. The fans of the power supply and the CPU cooler very briefly turn on, do a sort of jerking motion once and that's it. No post, no display, no beep code, no nothing. If I hold the power button, the fans sort of keep spinning like I'm trying to run them at a very low voltage.

But here comes the peculiar part. I plugged in the card while the PC was booted, partially out of laziness, and it was detected just fine. I ran lspci and it was there, the drivers auto-installed, I ran speedtest-cli on the card, and it worked perfectly, gigabit ethernet right there. What's going on? I restarted the PC, and it couldn't turn back on, same issue as before. But if I take the card out, and then plug it in about a second after I press the power button, it works perfectly fine.

Several things that I tested:

1. Tried a different beefier power supply, same issue.
2. Put the card on a different motherboard, worked fine.
3. Tried removing all other connections except the essential ones and the network card, same issue.
4. Disabled serial and parallel ports in the bios, suspecting an IRQ conflict, same issue.
5. Cleaned the PCI ports, same issue.
6. Reset the bios multiple times, with the battery disconnected and connected, same issue.
7. Tried looking for IRQ manual assignment in bios, wasn't there.
8. Reflashed the BIOS with the most recent version available, from 2013.

There's no doubt that inserting the card into a running system was a very bad idea, but I kind of got tunnel vision while looking for a solution.

My system specs:

- **CPU**: I3-2120 3.3 GHz running at 2.00 GHz, multiplier set to 20 for power saving reasons.
- **Motherboard**: Asrock H61m-DPS
- **RAM**: Adata 4 GB ddr3-1600Mhz, running at 1333Mhz
- **HDD**: 3x500 Gb, 1x320 Gb, all 7200 RPM
- **GPU**: GT 1030
- **PSU**: Currently on a generic 300-watt supply, tested with MasterWatt 550 power supply
- **Chassis**: Generic
- **OS**: OpenMediaVault 6, Debian 11 Bullseye

Here is the dmesg output without the card plugged in.

https://pastebin.com/Z1bYWBAX

And the lspci output:

```
root@openmediavault:~# lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200/2nd Generation Core Processor Family PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev b5)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev b5)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev b5)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 05)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation H61 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port Desktop SATA AHCI Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP108 [GeForce GT 1030] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GP108 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
03:00.0 PCI bridge: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1083/1085 PCIe to PCI Bridge (rev 04)
05:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 06)
```

Comment: Do you have Legacy PCI mode enabled in the BIOS?

Comment: There is no option specifying legacy PCI in bios [Page 52 in the motherboard manual](https://download.asrock.com/Manual/H61M-DPS.pdf) can be seen here. But CSM is enabled.

Comment: Please clarify: Did you test with or without under-clocking/volting the system? And don't do the hotswap thing again.... PCI suppports hot-swap, but most cards and motherboards DO NOT implement it well (or not at all).

Comment: @KasefTamjid Legacy Bios and CSM is more or less the same thing. Carefull with that one. If you disable it your system may NOT boot at all, because the boot-loader is then, in most cases, setup for legacy mode only.

Comment: @Tonny All testing was done under default conditions, with csm enabled and no over/underclocking. I realized a bit later how lucky I am and still wonder how I got through doing that multiple times... definitely not doing it again, until I get some solid leads.

Comment: My initial thoughts are that the motherboard is issuing conflicting resources at startup, but this gets resolved after the operating system loads up. Which also kinda doesn't make sense because I had to wait for about a second before plugging in the card and I think its far too short of a time for the os to load.

Comment: I ran lspci -vvv while the card was plugged in and remember seeing this 'Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 17'

Comment: @KasefTamjid Interrupt conflicts are not really a thing anymore since the ISA and VLB slots went extinct. That is also the reason modern biosses don't have config settings for those anymore. It just isn't needed anymore.

Comment: It is quite possible this combination of NIC and motherboard is simply iffy. Disabling Wake Up On LAN in the BIOS sometimes helps in my experience.

Comment: Wake up on LAN is disabled. and wasn't enabled at any time

Comment: are there any commands I can run after hot plugging the card *again* that may provide some helpful directions? If I have to take the risk, I want to get the most out of it.